# Can you teach Siri how to recognize the name of your app?

Tags: ios, siri

It is possible to open an app using Siri just by saying the name of the app.
If Siri doesn't recognize the name properly (for example if it's not an english word, she won't), you can prepend it with "Open 'app'" - and Siri will match app names slightly more liberally.

**Here's the question**: Is it possible to include a phonetic pronunciation with your own app so that Siri will understand it without using the "open"-keyword?

Kind of like you can define pronunciation for contact-names.

Comment: no there is no API for siri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now possible in iOS 11 using the INAlternativeAppNames key in your Info.plist as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1950/_index.html

```
<key>INAlternativeAppNames</key>
<array>
<dict>
    <key>INAlternativeAppName</key>
    <string>Unicorn Pay</string>
    <key>INAlternativeAppNamePronunciationHint</key>
    <string>you nee corn pay</string>
</dict>
</array>
```

Comment: but that Q&A you linked to specifically says "Note: Only include app name synonyms in `INAlternativeAppNames`. Do not include your app's bundle display name." and I think this question is about the pronunciation of the app's display name

Answer (score 0):

NO Apple has not released any APIs for Siri, from iOS 6 in 2012 to iOS 9 in 2015.

In 2012, you can only create your own siri proxy, but then it will only work on the network where the proxy is placed.

---

**In 2016, Apple is allowing to interact with Siri in iOS 10 using [SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/).**

Comment: I know there is no API for Siri, but I don't need an API. Siri already opens apps by recognizing the app name. I just want to define how the app name is pronounced.

Comment: Meaning that the way your app name is pronounced is then a custom function. Since all siri speech interoperation is done server side, it will need an API to change. Wich is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add an address book entry with the name of the App. Give a phonetic nickname to the address book entry corresponding to the pronunciation of the app. Siri should then open it when you say "Open [app])

Comment: The question was how to do it _without_ the `open` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, as it is. Siri is based on a speech recognition engine called Nuance, they offer a very decent SDK for iOS and Android. Nuance mobile gives you a demo account, that expires every 30 days, and allows you to do a finite amount (5000 or so) of speech recognition transactions. If you get a paid account you can teach (add custom vocabulary words) words to Nuance, and handle production levels of speech recognition traffic.