# Location Permission Popup does not use CFBundleSpokenName

Tags: ios, swift

When asking the user for access to his/her location using the `CLLocationManager` `subscribeToAuthorizationStatus` method, a system alert dialog is shown with the title **"Allow <'appname'> to access your location?"**

When using the accessibility voiceover for such a system alertview, the appname that is pronounced seems to be the `CFBundleDisplayName` and not the `CFBundleSpokenName`.

Is there any way to get the voiceover to pronounce the appname with the `CFBundleSpokenName` text?

Comment: what is your `CFBundleDisplayName` and what have you set for the `CFBundleSpokenName`?

Comment: `CFBundleDisplayName = "112 NL"` while the `CFBundleSpokenName = "One One Two NL"` (Dutch Emergency Number)

Comment: have you tried "One One Two en el"? If I am not wrong, the voice over will treat "NL" as one word, and that might be the issue.

Comment: NL is not the problem. The main problem is **one hunderd and twelf** instead of **one one two**

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47801734/7820107.

Comment: was that answer helpful? @Rool Paap

Comment: Not really. the `CFBundleSpokenName` is used everywhere, except for the title of a permission popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the voiceover to pronounce the appname with the CFBundleSpokenName text?

That's definitely what the `CFBundleSpokenName` is made for: if there's a native component that doesn't abide by this rule, I strongly recommend to open a radar in order to bring a solution as soon as possible.

About this key, the Apple documentation states:

> CFBundleSpokenName (String - iOS, macOS) **contains a suitable replacement for the app name when performing text-to-speech operations**. Include this key in your app bundle **when the spelling of your app might be mispronounced by the speech system**. For example, if the name of your app is “MyApp123”, you might set the value of this key to “My app one two three”.

If your appname isn't spelled out as you wish with VoiceOver, the `CFBundleSpokenName` should do the job wherever you are on your device: if your problem still exists in iOS 13, that's definitely a bug that should be reported.

⚠️ ⬛️◼️▪️ **EDIT**  ▪️◼️⬛️ ⚠️ *(2020/04/03)*

I wrote a **D**eveloper **T**echnical **S**upport **I**ncident *(no 732724589)* for this question and the Apple's answer admits that's a problem they can't provide a solution.

I submitted a bug report entitled **VoiceOver: the location Permission Popup does not use CFBundleSpokenName** with the reference **FB7650152** in order to have a solution as soon as possible.

Now, you know why the **Location Permission Popup does not use CFBundleSpokenName**.