# CFBundleSpokenName is not used as specified in the documentation

Tags: swift, macos, cfbundledisplayname

I'm working on a macOS app and my goal is to correct the way that macOS' speech system (more specifically the speak announcements) spells the app's name.

[image]

[image]

I'm interested in the case when the app requests attention and the system pronounces its name. So far I have 2 scenarios:

- app blocks the system's shutdown
- a window pops up inside the app (like the one that asks you to save your work before quitting the app)

The solution I've tried is modifying the CFBundleSpoken in the app's property list name because from the apple documentation description it should do exactly what I need.

> CFBundleSpokenName
> A replacement for the app name in text-to-speech operations.

However, the macOS's voice over never uses CFBundleSpokenName in the scenarios described above. It always uses the CFBundleDisplayName from the property list. I've tested these scenarios on macOS 12.6 and macOS 13.2.1 and the results are the same.

I am new to macOS so my questions are:

- when is CFBundleSpokenName actually used?
- how can I reach my desired result of correcting the way mac's voice over spells my app's name

Comment: That seems to be a bug, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/58281746/1187415 for a similar report.